# How to use the condensation algorithm available in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, particle-filter

I need to implement a software for tracking of moving objects in image streams using the condensation algorithm and the OpenCV library. I have read that OpenCV includes an implementation of this algorithm, but I did not find examples or tutorials that explain how to use the corresponding functions available in OpenCV.

The [`cvCreateConDensation`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#createcondensation) function allocates the [`CvConDensation`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#cvcondensation) structure and requires the dimension of the state vector (**`dynam_params`**), the dimension of the measurement vector (**`measure_params`**) and the number of samples (**`sample_count`**).

- The dimension of the state vector should refer to the object state: for example, if the state could be the center point of the tracked object, then the state vector should contain the two coordinates of the center of the object, so the dimension of the state vector should be 2 in this case; in a similar manner, if the state of an object is formed by ***S*** points belonging to its shape, then I will specify ***2*S*** as `dynam_params` value (ie the number of coordinates is equal to ***2*S***). Is this correct?
- The number of samples is the number of particles, therefore the parameter `sample_count` must be set with the number of particles to be used for the tracking of the object.
- What about the dimension of the measurement vector? What is the purpose the `measure_params` parameter?

The [`cvConDensInitSampleSet`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#cvConDensInitSampleSet) function initializes the sample set for the condensation algorithm. Which rule is used to initialize the sample set? Which distribution is used to initialize the sample set? Given the starting position and the bounding box of the object to be tracked, how does this function initialize the sample set?

What is the function that performs a complete interaction (*select*, *predict* and *measure*) of the algorithm? How do the samples are updated?

Is there any tutorial that explains in detail how to use the functions available in OpenCV?

Comment: http://answers.opencv.org/question/6985/syntax-for-particle-filter-in-opencv-243/ could help?

Comment: In recent months, I managed to solve the problem by implementing the algorithm without using OpenCV, but your link could be useful to other users.

Comment: have you released your code? (i'm working on multi target tracking with opencv and i'm searching for methods implementations paper references whatever)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A working example of condensation algorithm can be found in the Q&A of opencv and ross (same author):

http://answers.ros.org/question/55316/using-the-opencv-particle-filter-condensation/

and

http://answers.opencv.org/question/6985/syntax-for-particle-filter-in-opencv-243/

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://blogs.oregonstate.edu/hess/code/particles/) is another implementation of a particle filter, and the OpenCV and GSL libraries were used. The source code provided by the author is easy to read. Maybe you can learn something from it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would have been great to get a more specific answer, especially including examples of how exactly the functions mentioned in the question are used.

Comment: Unfortunately, the file containing the source code is no longer present on that website.